# Call back to the app in STTwitter Login in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter-oauth, sttwitter

I am building an iOS app and using STTwitter library for twitter login.I'm facing a problem
that after successful login web view is not call back to my app.

here is my code

```
       - (IBAction)tweetLogin:(id)sender
           {
               self.twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerKey:@"dnqYU387efhsa3yjXe1iutTP73m"
                                             consumerSecret:@"SrqwezPbjjoRsYDusdcb9238jbd23tFZmAdh2yNRompjRLd6WI"];

                _loginStatusLabel.text = @"Trying to login with Safari...";

                _loginStatusLabel.text = @"";
                [_twitter postTokenRequest:^(NSURL *url, NSString *oauthToken) {     
                  NSLog(@"-- url: %@", url);
                  NSLog(@"-- oauthToken: %@", oauthToken);
                 TwitterLoginWebView *webViewVC = [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TwitterLoginWebView"];
              [self presentViewController:webViewVC animated:YES completion:^{
              NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
              [webViewVC.webView loadRequest:request];
                   }];
                   } authenticateInsteadOfAuthorize:NO
                  forceLogin:@(YES)
                  screenName:nil
                 oauthCallback:@"myapp://twitter_access_tokens/"
                  errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                    _loginStatusLabel.text = [error localizedDescription];
                  }];
               self.twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerKey:@"dnqY237jbdfsyjXe1iutTP73m"
                                           consumerSecret:@"SrqwezPbjjasb43nfkjsd0yJkJtFZmAdh2yNRompjRLd6WI"]; 
                [_twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *bearerToken) {
                  [_twitter getUsersShowForUserID:nil orScreenName:@"barackobama"   includeEntities:nil successBlock:^(NSDictionary *user) {
                 NSString *profileImageURLString = [user valueForKey:@"profile_image_url"];
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:profileImageURLString];
             // UIImage *profileImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:url];      
               } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                 }];
            } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            }];
            }
```

Comment: Annnnddddddd...? What have to tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: See STTwitter iOS demo project, it implements this very use case. https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/tree/master/demo_ios You probably didn't add the support for URL scheme "myapp://" in your app.